# Finding input lines that contain more than 10 characters and less than 20

Tags: ruby

I have code for the following requirements

Input: A list of lines of text from the keyboard.

Output: Every input line that has > 10 characters but < 20 characters (not counting the new line), and that contains the string `"ed"`

I need to modify this code:

```
while(a=gets.chomp)
  puts a if a.length>10 and a.length<20 and a.include?'ed'
  break if a.length.zero?
end
```

to print all the lines once I am done writing all the input lines, which means that first I need to write all the lines using a keyboard, then after finishing, it will display only the lines that meet the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
input = [] # prepare container for good lines
while(a=gets.chomp)
  break if a.empty?
  input << a if a.length.between?(11..19) and a.include?('ed')
end
puts input.join "\n" # print them out
```

Just out of curiosity, if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is acceptable as input terminator:

```
puts "Use Ctrl+D to process"
puts $stdin.readlines.select {|l|
  l.length.between?(11..19) and l.include?('ed')
}
```

Or, even:

```
puts $stdin.each_line.inject([]) do |m,l|
  l.chomp!
  break m if l.empty?  
  m << l if l.length.between?(11..19) and l.include?('ed')
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you got `@stdin`, but that's not defined by Ruby, nor is a good way to access a standard I/O channel/stream. Use `STDIN`, or if you're allowing the code to reassign STDIN, STDOUT or STDERR, use `$stdin`. Those should be treated as globals, since that's what the underlying OS assumes they'll be in your code.

Comment: @theTinMan Oh, I took `@stdin` from the bottomless bowl of variables, called _mistyping_. Thanks, updated.

Comment: It's really useful to run your own examples in IRB or Ruby before submitting them. Then you'll know whether what you submit is valid and accurate. Once they work then you can simply copy/paste them and "mistyping" won't be an issue.

Comment: @theTinMan I did with `STDIN` and after copy-paste I realized that `$stdin` is better in example case. Thanks for the tip, anyway.